# Syntax for deep copying an array with the spread operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, deep-copy

I am aware of deep copying an object and array in the below ways,

**With Objects: Way1: JSON way**

```js
const obj1 = {
        id: 5,
        names: {
            first: 'tinu',
            last: {
                other: 'k'
            }
        }
    };
    
    //Deep copy way 1: JSON way
    const obj2  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
    
    // Modify the nested 2nd object
    obj2.names.last.other = 'f';
    
    console.log(obj1); // Prints { id: 5, names: { first: 'tinu', last: { other: 'k' } } }
    console.log(obj2); // Prints { id: 5, names: { first: 'tinu', last: { other: 'f' } } }
```

**With Objects: Way2: Spread syntax way**

```js
const obj1 = {
    id: 5,
    names: {
        first: 'tinu',
        last: {
            other: 'k'
        }
    }
};

//Deep copy way 2: Spread syntax way
const obj2 = {...obj1, names: {...obj1.names, last: {...obj1.names.last}}};

// Modify the nested 2nd object
obj2.names.last.other = 'f';

console.log(obj1); // Prints { id: 5, names: { first: 'tinu', last: { other: 'k' } } }
console.log(obj2); // Prints { id: 5, names: { first: 'tinu', last: { other: 'f' } } }
```

**With Arrays: Way1: JSON way**

```js
  const array1 = [['a'], 'b', 'c'];
    
    // Deep copy way 1: JSON way
    const array2  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1));
    
    //Modify the nested 2nd array
    array2[0].push('pushed');
    
    console.log(array1);
    console.log(array2);
```

What is the **spread syntax way** with arrays to deep copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each nested array, replace it with `[...originalArrayReference]`. If you have to replace particular indicies, slice the outer array before and after that index first:

```js
const array1 = [['a'], 'b', 'c'];
    
const array2  = [[...array1[0]], ...array1.slice(1)];

//Modify the nested 2nd array
array2[0].push('pushed');

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

For a more complicated example:

```js
const origArr = [
  [
    'foo',
    'bar'
  ],
  [
    'bar',
    'baz',
    ['nested1', 'nested2', 'nested3'],
    'baz',
    'buzz'
  ],
  'buzz'
];

const newArr = [
  [...origArr[0]],
  [
    ...origArr[1].slice(0, 2),
    [...origArr[1][2]],
    ...origArr[1].slice(0, 3)
  ],
  origArr[2]
];
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way without using the slice? as we also did not use any method while deep copying with objects.

Comment: Not easily. `.slice` plus spread *is* probably the best way to deep clone arrays when dealing with immutable structures. Spread works only when you have an array to spread, but in order to clone an array in the middle of another array, you need to also properly order the other items around that array-in-the-middle, which requires `.slice` (or by explicitly noting each index, which also removes the need for `...` there, but that's repetitive and inflexible)